# Debug and IE only JS bug

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-7

[image: IE bug]

I have an IE only bug, probably down to do stray character. I get this popup message, but I have no idea where the bug is. In FF the various extensions indicate exactly where the error is, but in this isn't an option. How would I go about tracking down where this error has occurred? IE7

**Update**
IE8 seems to be much better at debugging and has a browser mode to view as IE7. For those interested in the error, it was caused by frmUsername not existing

```
window.onload = function() {
        document.getElementById('frmLogin').frmUsername.focus();
    }
```

which is ignored in IE8

Comment: Can you get your hands on IE8? IE8 has a IE7 mode with a built in debugger.

Comment: FWIW my guess is that you have a trailing comma in an object literal. Something like `{a: 42, b: 21,}` (note the comma after 21). This causes errors in IE but not in other browsers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install IE8. It has far better debugger *and* IE7 mode. With luck the same error will occur and you will be able to track it down.

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding Firebug Lite to your html and debug with that in IE7

http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite

Comment: tragically, Firebug Lite doesn't include a debugger.  :-(  (as documented on the page you linked)

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells you the line on which the error occured. Open the response of URL in text editor and look on that line.

Comment: One could look in all JavaScript files attached to the page, though. In case of 5-10 files it might be OK.

Comment: @katspaugh probably the file under URL which ed209 covered with red in his screenshot

Comment: @hnatt that just had the top level domain, it was the homepage

Comment: @ed209, then my answer is wrong. I support katspaugh's answer. Try installing IE8, switch it to compatibility with IE7, recreate and debug the error.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing any code, it's not possible to be certain, but I'll be willing to bet I can guess what the error is.

I think you've fallen foul of the [Trailing Comma Of Death](http://www.enterprisedojo.com/2010/12/19/beware-the-trailing-comma-of-death/).

In Javascript, you may have an array that looks something like this:

```
var mydata = [160,
              431,
              117,
              84,
              ];
```

This will run perfectly in all browsers.... except IE.

....And the error it will give in IE is exactly the one you've described.

The reason? It's that comma after the `84` (or whatever your last item happens to be). It'll be the same if it's an object structure rather than an array.

Technically, IE is correct in rejecting this comma - it's not allowed in the Javascript spec. But all other browsers are happy to ignore it, so you get this situation of code that works in all browsers, but not in the one browser where it's virtually impossible to debug.

Hopefully this will be enough to help you locate the problem. More info (plus some fun graphics) at the site linked above.  :)

Comment: that was my first guess, but actually it turned out I was looking for a html element that didn't exist. Seems this is an error on IE7 but not IE8!

Comment: heh. ah well, the comma is by far the most common cause of this kind of bug. But well done for tracking it down (for the record, I would have also recommended the IE8 debugger in IE7-compatibility mode, if others hadn't already suggested it)

Comment: I got such error in IE when there was a property name of `default` in some object. Firefox no problem.

Answer (score -1):

open ie7
click f12 
click "start debugging"

**EDIT:**
download this:
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=18359

Then follow the steps above.

Comment: don't you mean IE8 or IE9. IE7 does not have a debugger. :)

Comment: AFAIK, the Developer Toolbar is not much more than a DOM inspector.

Comment: thanks, I tried the debugger in IE7 but I didn't get any more info. Upgrading to IE8